# How to scroll with mouse in tmux (not history, but terminal output)

Tags: tmux

This seemingly simple question, is one I cannot find an answer to. The solutions suggesting adding

```
setw -g mouse on
```

into the config, do not work. Yes, the mouse works, but on history. Not on the shell output. I cannot understand the logic behind this... why is this the default? Lets say I issue an ls command. I need to scroll to see the entire output, but tmux prevents this.

EDIT:

I would also like to know why is this the default behavior?  What prevents it from behaving like other terminals do?

Comment: You can type `C-a [` (Ctrl-a or b, depending on your prefix, then [) to enable scrolling through the buffer

Comment: Thank you both @jeremysprofile. Is there a way to enable scrolling by default? Seems "wrong" that if i run a cat command, I have to do extra things, to read its output. In the regular, or zsh, terminal, this is not needed. I hope I made my wording clear. +1

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. I had that problem as well, and my solution was "I'm going to be an adult and only use the keyboard". You can find other people's struggles by searching for something like "tmux scroll through buffer by default" but all the solutions provided look super janky  or use plugins.

Comment: In the time that has transpired, I managed to get the keyboard working as I want. I am all set now, and I too dont need a mouse :) Seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when using Tmux from within iTerm2 on a Mac.  I fixed it by going to "Preferences" in iTerm2 and then to the "Advanced" tab.  Within there were a bunch of general topics (and a really long list of stuff), and one of them was "Mouse", or something like that.  Within there, there was an option that said "Scoll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode."  This was set to "Yes".  I set it to "No", and the problem of went away (i.e. scrolling on my mouse pad no longer made it go back through my command history).

Comment: Works! Precisely its now under `iTerm2 > Settings > Advanced > search ("wheels sends arrow") > Turn No`

Comment: The above setting is great, its now moved to "Scroll Wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode" > No

Answer (score 1):

Two items to be aware of:

Regarding the comment that you posted

1. `setw -g mouse on`

   ^ Works on my machine; I am guessing it fails in your config.

   To test locally: go to tmux and type:

   `<leader> colon`

   For my setup that is `ctrl b :`

   That puts you in command mode.

   Now paste: `setw -g mouse on`

   Use the same process to toggle it off `setw -g mouse on` and verify that there is a difference.

If your problem still is not solved:
(at-least on a mac terminal) Try step #2

2. Ensure that mouse reporting is checked

   See image:

[image]

Hope that helps, your question helped me with my configs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by pressing the standard (ctrl + b) and then page up i was able to scroll with either mouse, arrows or page up / page down.

Answer (score -2):

You can immediately enter copy mode by holding `Shift` during your first scroll. Then you can keep holding shift to continue scrolling, or you can release it and control cursor with scrolling move. Tested it on tmux v2.6+.
You still have to set `setw -g mouse on` for that to work.